# cross validation on my different models in R

Tags: r, model, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation

I have a dataset of bike-rent data including the number of rentals, temperature, windspeed, humditity, etc.

I have used multiple regression models in R, using all different kind of packages. The models I used are: Conditional inference tree, Linear regression, Random Forest, Neural networks (using different configurations), recursive partioning and regression trees and Support Vector Machines.

Now I want to test the performance of each model using 10-fold Cross Validation. What is the best way to do this? Is there a package that I can use to perform 10-fold Cross Validation on each model?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The [`caret` package](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cvTools is what you're looking for.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cvTools/cvTools.pdf